# Why is Node's process.stdin.on('readable') fire my callback once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stream

I have the following code:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  const input = process.stdin.read();
  console.log(input);
});
```

In a tutorial, the callback seems to fire in a loop, but when I try it, it gets called only once, then exits. Why is this happening? My Node version is `13.12.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `readable` event fires, it won't fire again until either the stream reaches the end or until you call `.read()` and get `null` back (no more data to read).  Once you get `null`, then it will fire again when there is more data.

That's why the sample code in the doc does this:

```
const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('readable', function() {
  // There is some data to read now.
  let data;

  while (data = this.read()) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

In general, this is a more difficult way to use streams.  If you use them in the flowing mode such as this:

```
process.stdin.on('data', (input) => {
  console.log(input);
});
```

Then, it will just call you whenever data arrives.